# InitializeSecurityContext (Kerberos) C++ client with ApacheDs kdc

Tags: c++, windows, kerberos, sasl, sspi

I'm trying to do SASL auth betweeen a windows C++ client and a java server. On the client side I'm doing:

```
AcquireCredentialsHandle(NULL, "Kerberos", SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, NULL,
                         &credentials, NULL, NULL, &hCred, &tsExpiry);
scRet = InitializeSecurityContext(&hCred, NULL, targetName,
                                  ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY, 0,
                                  SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP, NULL, 0,
                                  hContext, &OutBuffer,
                                  &dwSSPIOutFlags, &tsExpiry);
```

with:

```
credentials = ("myuser","mypassword", "MYDOMAIN.ORG")
targetName = "myservice/node0"
```

the domain has no relation with the windows client domain.

The result I got at the moment is:

```
scRet = SEC_E_NO_AUTHENTICATING_AUTHORITY
```

I know that the kerberos implementation for InitializeSecurityContext should contact the ApacheDS kdc and ask for a ticket, so I think that the first problem to solve here is: how the inizialize function can discover hostname and port of the kdc server (which are localhost:6088 by the way)?

I tried using ksetup:

```
ksetup /AddKdc MYDOMAIN.ORG localhost:6088
```

but with no luck.